# Excel saves absolute references to other sheets in my workbook. This causes problems when emailing the workbook to colleagues

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have this the following problem.

I create a pivottable and set a reference to anther Sheet, for example:

```
=Sheet1!A:C
```

When I save, copy, cut and paste file to various locations, I end up with the source path:

```
=C:\Oldfilepath\[Oldfilename.xlsx]Sheet1!A:C
```

This is highly undesirable since new versions of the file will reference source data in old versions of the file, and colleagues I email will have references to my computer in their file. I of course the pivottable to still reference

```
=Sheet1!A:C
```

despite me having copied/pasted, cut/pasted or emailed the file.

I've had this problem for several months and it really bothers me. I read in another thread that I should check "update links to other documents" and "save external link values". That didn't solve the problem.

I've also read a recommendation to refer to a range instead. That didn't solve the problem either.

```
=ExportRange
```

became

```
=C:\Oldfilepath\[Oldfilename.xlsx]ExportRange
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

I use Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to 'options' in the 'advanced section' you find several ticks to choose:

(you have to scroll down a bit)

e.g.

- update links to external resources
- save external link values
- ask to update links

  and also something related to large pivotal tables.

T.